# Testing the object type of a parameter passed into a actionscript function?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

How do you check if an `Object` passed into a function is the one you are expecting?

```
public function writeRecord(grid:IExtendedDataGrid, record:Object):String
{

    ExternalInferface.call("alert","record " + record);

    if (record.contains("HotListItem")
    {
        //# I have found my object

    }
    else
    {
        //# Wrong type of object

    }

}
```

When I display my object to the ExternalInterface `alert` call it displays the following...

> record [object HotListItem]

I would like to be able to test for this type of Object beforehand.

Comment: Where does the term `HotListItem` come from? I mean how did the `alert()` know to show that specific text about `record`? Knowing the answer to that question will also give you an answer to your problem...

Comment: Use the **is** operator as following: **if (record is HotListItem)**.

Comment: Thanks Organis. HotListItem is a custom class. I tried "record instanceof HotListItem" and it worked but said it was deprecated and prompted me to use "is" instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the **is** operator has resolved my question.
I tried the instanceof operator but this was flagged as deprecated.

Thanks to Organis

```
if (record is HotListItem)
```